# How to wait periods of 30 second to run a service

Tags: android, service, timer, sleep

I, i have a service and i want that once it started, it performs is work 
every 30 seconds. How can i do that?

Tnk
Valerio

Comment: Maybe this link helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Handler usage example for your Service (Bind part of the Service is missing):

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.os.Handler;

public class PeriodicService extends Service {

private Handler mPeriodicEventHandler;

    private final int PERIODIC_EVENT_TIMEOUT = 30000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();

      mPeriodicEventHandler = new Handler();
      mPeriodicEventHandler.postDelayed(doPeriodicTask, PERIODIC_EVENT_TIMEOUT);
    }

    private Runnable doPeriodicTask = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            //your action here
            mPeriodicEventHandler.postDelayed(doPeriodicTask, PERIODIC_EVENT_TIMEOUT);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        mPeriodicEventHandler.removeCallbacks(doPeriodicTask);      
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

I also found an example of another class called [Handler](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html) (that is available for Android) that apparently should work better when using the UI.