# Android, how to make a thread sleep?

Tags: java, android

Here's my code that, upon a click of the "menu" button, slides 'menubtm' in or out of view. Is there a way to make it pause for a few milliseconds at every loop, so that it would be viable, how the menubtm moves?

Thanks!

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event ) {
 if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){

    if ( menuBtmVisable == true )
    {
        menuBtmVisable = false;
        int xnow = menuBtmTopLimit;
        while (xnow<menuBtmTopLimit+120)
        {   
        xnow+=1;
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(480, 120, 0, xnow);
        menubtm.setLayoutParams(lp); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        menuBtmVisable = true;
        int xnow = menuBtmTopLimit+120;
        while (xnow>menuBtmTopLimit)
        {
        xnow-=1;
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams lp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(480, 120, 0, xnow);
        menubtm.setLayoutParams(lp); 
        }
    }

 }
 return super.onKeyDown(keycode,event); 
}
```

**EDIT:
Thanks to your advice, I did it with animations.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0"
android:toYDelta="120"
android:duration="500"
 />
```

**This animation has to make the menu slide 120 px down... it does so ok, but then springs back into the old place. Is there a way to make it stay in the new location?**

**EDIT2 : got it!**

```
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:fillAfter="true"
```

Comment: Check out the comments/answers from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of hacking it yourself, use [Android Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html), which is designed exactly for this sort of thing. It will be much more stable and probably look much better in the end.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the title: `Thread.sleep` will make a thread sleep.

That said, you probably don't want to do that here. If I'm understanding your snippet, `onKeyDown` is being called from the UI thread. You don't want to delay the UI thread either by sleeping or by doing processing that will take a while. Instead you should start an animation and return as fast as you can. See [View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html) and [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html) in the Android Dev Guide for two ways of doing animation. (Note that the latter requires 3.x or higher.)

Comment: thinks, I did it with animation ( see edit above ), but now after animation it springs back into the old place... what should I do to keep it in its new location?