# how a wait and then restart. (android)

Tags: android, service, wait

Hi I got a service in android and I want it to update something every 10 seconds. So I was thinking of having a wait and then restart the function (cant think of what to call it). Any ideas on how to do a wait in a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use threading. This can be done with something like this.

```
public void onClick(View v) {  
new Thread(new Runnable() {   
 public void run() {      
//Your code for whatever goes in here
  }
  }).start();
}
```

You can then call `thread.sleep(10000)`. The 10000 translates to 10 seconds.

If you look at the accepted answer on this post the posters code shows all of this in an excellent way to understand.

[Old SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Use thread in your service and for wait use thread.sleep(10000)...

Answer (score 1):

Use an [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). This will run your service at your scheduled time, and stops the service when it's done, ready to start again via the AlarmManager.