# how to fix a particular time interval for sending data from android mobile to a webserver?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

i have been using eclipse to create an app on android for sending data to a server through GPS.
the app that i have developed is sending the data for every second .. but i cant change the time intervals... can anyone tell me a way or code to send data from my app to server for once in every 2 minutes.

Comment: how do you manage to send your data? some code snippet?

Comment: send mail id i'll send you the code

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Java, the best option you have is of Thread.

And use **sleep()** method.

Try this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use [alarm manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)..