# Stop SpeechRecognizer from requesting audio focus

Tags: android

How can I stop `SpeechRecognizer` from requesting **audio focus**? I want to **disable** SpeechRecognizer's **beep** (**mute** all audio is **not** a solution) while `MediaPlayer` could still play some audio files (in another context - service)

So in my app I request audio focus only for service with MediaPlayer (*audio-service*)

```
...
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            int result = am.requestAudioFocus(null,
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                ...
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
```

SpeechRecognizer instance in another service (*speech-service*):

```
speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
```

When SpeechRecognizer starts listening in speech-service (`speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);`) it automatically requests audio focus and it still can play this annoying beep sound. At the same time in audio-service I get `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT` in `OnAudioFocusChangeListener` and I have code lines to pause MediaPlayer when audiofocus loss happens

So is it even possible to disable SpeechRecognizer's beep without muting sound (STREAM_MUSIC/STREAM_SYSTEM) or not using root?

Comment: Hi, do you found any solution

Comment: @Bahu, there is no solution

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21935042/3142611) but it's not a preferable  method

Comment: @Bahu yes it just disables all sounds for your app