# Prolonging the focusabilty of a View

Tags: android, focus

in my application I'm using instead of Buttons, ImageViews which have a selector as background. They are working fine though the focus is lost really quickly and as a result the effect isn't visible to the user 100%. Is there a way that I can delay the focus which the views receive for like a second? another way that I've tried was to change the ImageView's background when it was touched and change it back on the onPause()

**Background Selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/actionbar_background" />
<item  android:state_focused="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

**normal.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>    
</shape>
```

Comment: provide the selector plz

Comment: Have you tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android

postDelayed() method:

Comment: I'm not sure that it's helps, but try to remove android:state_focused="false"

Comment: Why would that improve the time that the effect takes place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what I did to overcome it I changed the background selector as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/actionbar_background" />
<item android:state_selected="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/actionbar_background" />
<item  android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

and on the function bound by the image view

```
v.setSelected(true);
selectedView = v;
```

and on onStop()

```
selectedView.setSelected(false);
```

Hope this will help anyone who stumbles upon this post