# android studio pause counting loop

Tags: android, android-studio

So the title says what i need. Here a code where it should work.

```
public void Left (View view)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
      "Time pause for 1 sec"
      Player.setX(Player.getX() + 5);
   }
}
```

postDelayed don't works and the other ones dont pause because it is the only code that is working

So I would need a short code to stop only the counting loop for 1 sec.
Is there a method for this.
It also can be a long code that works in there and could you show me the code with my code please.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android

Comment: I'm pretty new so could your maybe show wich one you would use and show me it on my code

Comment: The accepted solution seems fine. Just replace my_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.defaultcard); with Player.setX(Player.getX() + 5); and change 2000 to 1000

Comment: What i do with my_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
 ?

Comment: PostDelayed doesn' work in my programm