# SOS flashlight - How to

Tags: java, android, sos, flashlight

I made a flashlight app and now I want to add sos morse code flashing. This is my code for it but it doesen't work quite well, it blinks too fast so I need some kind of a delay, can anyone help?

```
public void sos(View v) {
    String myString = "111000111";
    Handler handler = new Handler();


    for (int x = 0; x < myString.length(); x++) {
        if (myString.charAt(x) == '1') {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    camera.startPreview();
                }
            }, 300);


            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                 }
            }, 300);


            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                }
            }, 300);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand what the problem is, then each Handler is running after 300 milliseconds. There is not a 300 millisecond delay between each one. If you want to do that, then you need to start another thread at the end of another one

Comment: can you do it for me? I just started learning this so I'm not really able to do that

Comment: You could also use `Thread.sleep()`, but that will halt the app's main thread

Comment: I don't know how to do that :/ please make it for me

Comment: Why are you using handler.postDelayed?  I would try somehting simpler like Thread.sleep()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  I am not an app programmer, but here is a sample of Thread.sleep().  Good luck.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < myString.length(); x++) {
    if (myString.charAt(x) == '1') {                
          params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
          camera.setParameters(params);
          camera.startPreview();
    }     
    Thread.sleep(300);      


    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    camera.setParameters(params);


}
```

Comment: This will likely crash the app as sleeping the main thread is bad, but it's as good a start as any. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3039718/2308683

Answer (score 0):

Second take on it.  Assuming it is true you can't sleep the main thread, try this:

```
int delay=0;
for (int x = 0; x < myString.length(); x++) {
    if (myString.charAt(x) == '1') {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                    camera.startPreview();
                }
            }, (delay+=300));


        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(params);
                 }
            }, (delay+=300));




        }

    }
```