# Can I pause a program for a while?

Tags: android, thread-sleep

I was creating an android app in which I need to show an imageview for 2 seconds and then another one ; I know that there are different ways to do it (in fact i've already solved this problem) but I was wondering if does it exist a special function like delay() (for Arduino environment) that stops the program for a while so I can write 2 setimageresource one after the other. 
I know it may seem a stupid question but it's just a curiosity ... Thank you for your attention

Comment: I think this post will help you with what you need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android

Comment: You shouldn't block the main thread. You could use a [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)