# Set wait time before the sound of a button starts

Tags: android-studio

I set a sound when I check the button

```
    public void Button(View v) {  

        final MediaPlayer mpStart = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.startsound); 
        mpStart.start();
        }
```

I want to wait some time before the sound starts. 
How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use Handler.postDelayed() method.

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {

// This solution will leak memory!  Actually don't use!!!
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
     @Override 
     public void run() { 

          final MediaPlayer mpStart = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.startsound); 
          mpStart.start();
     } 
}, 2000); //Here change the time to wait in milliseconds 
}
```

For more Info look here: [Pause a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android)