# Implement a time delay in android application

Tags: java, android

Below is a peice of code where on click the player will make their move by placing the X counter and then the computer will make their move by placing a O counter. The
only issue with this code currently is that when the player places their X counter, the O counter is placed as well at the same time. So it looks like both the player
and the computer has made their moves at the same time and that happens everytime the player makes their move.

What I want to ask, is it possible to include like a 2 second time delay so that the player will place their X and then after 2 seconds the computer will place their O?

Thanks in advance

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        if (playerOneMove) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
            ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerX);
            computerMove();
        }
}

private void computerMove() {
    String[][] field = new String[3][3];
    Random random = new Random(); //you may want to declare this as a class field
    List<Button> emptyButtons = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            if (field[i][j].equals("")) {
                emptyButtons.add(buttons[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    Button selectButton;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                && field[i][2].equals("")){
            //prevent win/win on rows by selecting the correct button here
        }
        else if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                && field[i][1].equals("")){
             //prevent win/win on rows by selecting the correct button here
        }
        else if (field[i][1].equals(field[i][2])
                && field[i][0].equals("")){
            //prevent win/win on rows by selecting the correct button here
        }
        else {
            selectButton = emptyButtons.get(random.nextInt(emptyButtons.size()));
        }

    selectButton.setText("O");
    selectButton.setTextColor(playerO);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this issue on pausing a thread will help you [how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android)

Comment: Isn't it better to create handler/task then to block whole UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put computer logic inside handler or timer task: [How to call a method after a delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072173/how-to-call-a-method-after-a-delay-in-android)

but you also need some flag, that will block user placing X while you are waiting for computer to make it move.

Comment: ok that seems to make sense. The flag, I am just wondering how to set the true or false. I'm guessing let's call the variable playerCanMove = true. When it's computerMove which is in handler, set playerCanMove = false and then after the the code where ...setText('O'), change the playerCanMove = true. Is that the correct ball park? If not can you place a little example please on the flagging

Comment: but then saying that I have 'isPlayerMove' already as a lfag so I wonder if I can just use that instead but just wondering how to block the player making a move

Comment: You already have if(playerOneMove) if you check there if player is allowed to move, then you don't need no additional checks.

Comment: Yeah thought so, sorry I was over thinking it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

i edited your onclick with the delay and i think you gonna need some sort of the flag wich blocks user until computer makes the move !

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
        return;
    }

    if (playerOneMove) {
        ((Button) v).setText("X");
        ((Button) v).setTextColor(playerX);

          //2000 is your delay in mills format
        v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                computerMove();
            }
        },2000)

    }
}
```

and i think it would be good idea to use some random number between 1sec to 3sec for delay and not the constant delay it creates better experience for user

Comment: Thanks Amir, I want to know if you can place an example of the flagging so I can work out what I need to do in terms of implementing the flagging?

Comment: @BigHendo you can have a Boolean variable and when there is computer turn you set that variable to true and when computer makes the move you set that variable to false and in user OnClick you should check this variable and if it was false than user can make a move

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the **Handler** and **Runnable** class in android. You can delayed the time of a method as required.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Do something after 100ms
  }
}, 100);
```