# How to make a visual demonstration of the 15 puzzle optimal solution

Tags: android, multithreading

I tried to make pauses between moves by using `Thread.sleep` but it doesn't work properly. When I start demo, the screen just freezes and after a few seconds shows me a resolved puzzle... This is my code:

```
// starting a demonstration
public void startDemo() {
    ArrayList<Integer> shortestPath = Algorithms.getShortestPath(); // getting the sequence of tile numbers to move
    for (Integer tileNumber: shortestPath) {
        try {
            board.move(tileNumber); // moving a tile
            boardView.invalidate(); // redraw on screen
            Thread.sleep(500); // trying to make a pause between moves
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I read that blocking UI thread is a bad practice. But what is the best way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Use the  `Handler.postDelayed()` method.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3039718/646887

Comment: If I understood everything correctly, the ``Thread.sleep`` does not release locks. So You should maybe try ``Thread.wait`` ?