# Android App Crashes with while loop

Tags: android

I'm  making this app that tells how much longer till we reach a destination but whenever I try to use it it just black screens just crashes. I think it has something to do with the loop but I can't find anything online Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.................................................................................................................

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.time.*;
import java.math.*;

public class TimeTIll extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String DateUtils = null;
    TextView txt;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_till);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TimeDipslay);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10) {
            Program();
            i++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Program() {

        int totalMinutesSinceMidnight = 0;
        long ms = 0;
        long secondsM = 0;
        long SecondsTillEstimate = 0;
        long SecondsTillArrival1 = 0;
        double MinutesTillArrival = 0;
        double hoursTillArrival = 0;
        double SecondsTillArrival = 0;
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar midnight = Calendar.getInstance();
        midnight.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        midnight.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        midnight.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        midnight.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }


        now = Calendar.getInstance();
        midnight = Calendar.getInstance();

        ms = now.getTime().getTime() - midnight.getTime().getTime();
        totalMinutesSinceMidnight = (int) (ms / 1000);
        secondsM = totalMinutesSinceMidnight;

        SecondsTillEstimate = (60 * 60 * 23);
        SecondsTillArrival1 = SecondsTillEstimate - secondsM;
        hoursTillArrival = Math.floor(SecondsTillArrival1 / 3600);
        SecondsTillArrival1 -= (hoursTillArrival * 3600);
        MinutesTillArrival = Math.floor(SecondsTillArrival1 / 60);
        SecondsTillArrival1 -= (MinutesTillArrival * 60);
        SecondsTillArrival = SecondsTillArrival1;
        txt.setText((int) hoursTillArrival + " Hours " + (int) MinutesTillArrival + " Minutes " + (int) SecondsTillArrival + " Seconds Till Arrival In Floriada");

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read about the [activity life-cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle). You cannot call long-running tasks in `onCreate` and expect them to show anything other than an ANR crash (your `onCreate` method blocks the UI thread with all those sleep statements and generates an ANR crash before it even gets to the `onStart` and `onResume` stages where it actually shows the activity).

If you want the UI to change dynamically, you could use a handler to execute a method at a regular interval. For example, to update something at a regular interval (1000 ms here) you could do:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private TextView txt;
    private int count = 0;
    private final int updateFreqMs = 1000; // call update every 1000 ms

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateTime();
                handler.postDelayed(this, updateFreqMs);
            }
        }, updateFreqMs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_till);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.TimeDipslay);
    }

    private void updateTime() {
        // here you update the displayed value
        // this will be called every second indefinitely
        // do your math and generate a string to print, just showing
        // a counter here to demonstrate
        ++count;
        txt.setText("Count = " + count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are trying to make sleep the main thread of the application. In Android I knew that for security reasons this can't be done.
(Look this https://www.codementor.io/tips/0743378261/non-freezing-sleep-in-android-app for details )

Try this solution instead:

[How to pause / sleep thread or process in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You Shouldn`t use it inside main thread specially when you are doing operation inside it.
You may have to use some thing like that.

```
   viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (statues==true){
            if (statue==true){
                delay(500)
                   //ToDo


             }
        }
    }
```