# Start data in Firebase - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get a value from the firebase, i want to change the value in the firebase and then reset the old value, but my code will fetch the original value after the code is executed.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private int leaf1R;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

            DatabaseReference leaf1RRef = database.getReference("leaf1").child("r");
            leaf1RRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Integer red = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                    leaf1R=red;
                    Log.i("MyLeaf", "Catch: "+leaf1R);

                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.w("MyLeaf", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                }
            });

            leaf1RRef.setValue(255);
            Log.d("MyLeaf", "Put max value");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            leaf1RRef.setValue(leaf1R);
            Log.d("MyLeaf", "Put old value");
        }
    }

}
}
```

**My output is:**

Put max value

Put old value

Catch: 255

**I want:**

Catch: 255

Put max value

Put old value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. Instead of waiting for the database to become available, your main code continues. Then when the data is available, your `onDataChange` gets called with a snapshot of that data.

For this reason, all code that needs the data must be (called from) inside `onDataChange`. So a very simple fix for your problem could be:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

DatabaseReference leaf1RRef = database.getReference("leaf1").child("r");
leaf1RRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Integer red = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
        leaf1R=red;
        leaf1RRef.setValue(255);
        Log.d("MyLeaf", "Put max value");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("MyLeaf", "Put old value");
        leaf1RRef.setValue(leaf1R);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        Log.w("MyLeaf", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

Note that this code still block the main/UI thread in `onDataChange`, which Android does not take kindly to. So while it may work in testing, a `Thread.sleep()` may cause the OS to kill/penalize your app. See this question for an alternative way of delaying the second `setValue()`: [How to pause / sleep thread or process in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520887/how-to-pause-sleep-thread-or-process-in-android)