# Android Studio is not reading the retreived data from Firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data from Firebase but it is not read by android studio although I am using the tutorial

I tried to copy the link that is sent by Android Studio to Firebase:

DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("USERS").child(uID).child("DeviceID");
textview.setText(myRef.toString());

and past the result in the browser and it shows me the result in firebase but when I try to use it to get data it is not retrieving anything. 
here is how I am trying to read it by calling a function:

textview.setText(ReadDeviceId);

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
   private String ReadDeviceId(){

    FBUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    uID = FBUser.getUid();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("USERS").child(uID).child("DeviceID");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            r_deviceID = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            r_deviceID = "no userID";
        }
    });
    return r_deviceID;
}
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Knowing that my firebase database security rule is:
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

{

"rules": {

".write": "auth != null",

".read": true

}

}

'''''''''''''''''''

but nothing is displayed

Comment: can you show me the error?

Comment: it does not give error it just do not display anything @HussainAbbas

Comment: any warnings?.  goto your logcat and search for this "wrapper" and let me know if you found anything

Comment: @HussainAbbas when I run it nothing happen the application works fine just the textview that should display the DeviceID is empty and not shown

Comment: okay can you show me your data in Firebase

Comment: i want to see its structure

Comment: @HussainAbbas the search for the wrapper shows

Comment: app305
   USERS
      Iy19sCJUeLg59KQ15UuHUUB35Jz1
         DeviceID: "amz4cde "

Comment: @HussainAbbas I am new in stackoverflow so I do not know how to show image

Comment: its okay i understand your error i will post the code try it and let me know

Comment: @HussainAbbas thank you, the writing works fine to me but the reading it is not displaying any data although when I test the link on a browser it gives me result... thank you one more time

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
 private String ReadDeviceId(){
      FBUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
      uID = FBUser.getUid();
      FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
      DatabaseReference myRef = 
           database.getReference("USERS").child(uID).child("DeviceID");

     myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             for(Datasnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren)
             {
                //try to map it with your on model class and replace the String with your model class
                r_deviceID = snapshot.getValue(String.class)
             }
             //r_deviceID = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
             r_deviceID = "no userID";
           }
     });
     return r_deviceID;
 }
```

Comment: check it ouy and let me know if there is any problem

Comment: log it and check the values

Comment: i think it is returning the r_deviceID before it get the data

Comment: i tried to make the program hold 5 second before running the getDeviceId function and it return the value... but i don't know if it is recommended to make the program hold like this

Comment: did you call this function in oncreate?

Comment: I make a function that read the DeviceID from firebase and a function that displays the result... I run the function that reads the DeviceID at onCreate then after holding 5 seconds I run the function that display the result... thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your `ReadDeviceId()` function, you are returning the value of `r_deviceID` before it is set (event listeners are not synchronous). Therefore, your `textview.setText(ReadDeviceId());` will always be `textview.setText(null);`, which will show nothing.

For your use case, you should change `addValueEventListener` to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and set the textview's value from within the handler itself like this:

```
private String ReadDeviceId(){
    FBUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    uID = FBUser.getUid();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("USERS").child(uID).child("DeviceID");

    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                textview.setText(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                textview.setText("no userID");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i tried to make the program hold 5 second before running the getDeviceId function and it return the value... but i don't know if it is recommended to make the program hold like this

Comment: That's a separate question entirely. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3039718/3068190) for how to properly delay function execution.